# App keeps crashing creating a PygLatin Game - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I am new to objective C programming.

I created a PygLatin application but it keeps crashing it. Do tell me if you have spotted any problems with my code.

> **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]'
>    **First throw call stack:**

would appreciate all the help I can get thanks! :)

```
@implementation RootViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.userInputTextField.delegate = self;

    self.userInputTextField.text = @"";
}

-(void)print: (NSString*)printWords {
    self.resultLabel.text = @"%@", printWords;
}

-(void)charsplitter: (NSArray*)charArraysplitter {
    //word selection loop
    int indexCount = 0;
    for(indexCount = 0; indexCount < charArraysplitter.count; indexCount++)
    {
        self.wordsToBeSplit = charArraysplitter[indexCount];

        NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[self.wordsToBeSplit length]];

        [self.wordsToBeSplit enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, self.wordsToBeSplit.length)
    options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
   usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
           [characters addObject:substring];
        }];
    [self vowelsComparator:characters];
    }
}

-(void)vowelsComparator: (NSArray*)comparator {
    self.myVowels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"a", @"e", @"i", @"o",@"u", nil];
    int charIndex;
    self.subsequentCharCount = 0;
    for(charIndex = 0; charIndex < comparator.count; charIndex++)
        //loops to find if first character is a vowel
    if([self.myVowels containsObject:comparator[0]]){
        [self print: self.userInputTextField];  NSLog(@"working fine:");
    }else{
        //loops to find other vowels
        while (self.subsequentCharCount < comparator.count){
            self.subsequentCharCount++;
            if ([self.myVowels  containsObject:comparator[self.subsequentCharCount]]){
                //moving the consonants behing the vowels
                NSLog(@"working fine:");
                NSString *combinedWords = [[self.wordsToBeSplit substringFromIndex:self.subsequentCharCount]stringByAppendingString:[self.wordsToBeSplit substringToIndex:self.subsequentCharCount]];
                NSString *completedWord = [combinedWords stringByAppendingString:@"ay"];
                [self print: completedWord];
            }
        };
    }
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];//resigns the keyboard every time return button is pressed
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)pygButton:(id)sender
{
    self.inputText = [self.userInputTextField.text lowercaseString];//user input  is lowercase
    NSArray *wordsArray = [self.inputText componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];    //separate words into arrays.
    [self charsplitter: wordsArray];
}

@end
```

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put
 `self.subsequentCharCount++;`
 at the end of while loop means below
 `[self print: completedWord];`

Comment: I did what you said but my resultLabel only shows %@  for words that starts with vowels and and for some words it automatically crashes citing a **index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9** varies between words.

Comment: in your print method self.resultLabel.text = @"%@", printWords

Comment: directly assign printWords self.resultLabel.text = printWords;